# Verifying only "code" using CognitoUser (npm: amazon-cognito-identity-js)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, authentication, npm, amazon-cognito

I am currently using the following while implementing "forget password" functionality,
but **I wanted to verify "verification code" only first, and "password" later**
but right now it wants both parameters new password and code to verify and update password at the same time.

```
   getUser(values.email).confirmPassword(values.code, values.password, {
          onSuccess: (data) => {
            console.log("onSuccess", data); 
            setStage(2);
          },
          onFailure: (data) => {
            console.log("onFail", data);
            return;
          },
        });
const getUser = (Username) => {
  return new CognitoUser({ Username, Pool });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much you can do about this behavior. This is simply how the API endpoint in Cognito works. The [ConfirmForgotPassword](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ConfirmForgotPassword.html) endpoint has both the code and the new password as mandatory parameters. The response will tell you if the password was incorrect (if it does not match with the configured rules) or if the code was invalid/expired.

The code is delivered only to the end device. It means you will never see it and therefore cannot tell if it's the correct one or not. That is something Cognito will do.

Comment: Thanks, Also  I observed that when we make an instance of CognitoUser
it does not throws an error if the email/username wasn't even present in the pool, it just proceeds